# SYMPY : How to simplify expression with exponential functions?

Tags: sympy

I have expression with exponential functions and I would like to simplify them. Some of the exponential functions have a negative parameters.

To sum up my problem with a very trivial example :

```
a,b,c,d=sp.symbols("a b c d",real=True, positive=True)
myExpr=(sp.exp(c)+sp.exp(d))*sp.exp(-c-d)
```

`myExpr.simplify()` gave a simplified expression. That is perfect.

**BUT**, **with a denominator in the expression**, exponential functions with a negative parameter are not simplified :

```
a,b,c,d=sp.symbols("a b c d",real=True, positive=True)
myExpr=(sp.exp(c)+sp.exp(d))*sp.exp(-c-d)/a
```

How can I simplify it ?

As suggested in the comments, I submit a more complicated example :

```
import sympy as sp
a, b, c, d, e, f, c1, c2, t = sp.symbols("a b c d e f c_1 c_2 t", real=True, positive = True)
myExpr=((c1*sp.exp((a+b+c)*t)+c2*sp.exp((d+e+f)*t)))/(c1+c2)*sp.exp(-(a+b+c+d+e+f)*t)
```

And I would like an output as this one :

```
output= ((c1*sp.exp(-(e+d+f)*t)+c2*sp.exp(-(a+b+c)*t)))/(c1+c2)
```

Rq : with (a+b+c) in the same exp : *exp ( -(a+b+c)*t )* and not as a product of exp : *exp(-a*t)*exp(-b*t)*exp(-c*t)*, similarly for (d+e+f)

Thanks for answer.

Comment: You can use `factor_terms(expand(myExpr))`

Comment: @OscarBenjamin. Thanks for answer. It works for this simple example. But, on more complex examples, the expand function adds extra-terms. So, concerning exponential functions, my expressions are simplified but I get extra-terms. Is there a mean to group exponential terms only ? It seems that the problem is due to the negative value of the paremeters. My example is not simplified but `myExpr=(sp.exp(c)+sp.exp(d))*(sp.exp(-c-d)+sp.exp(-c-d))/a` is simplified with `myExpr.simplify()`

Comment: If you want to ask about a more complicated example then you'll need to show a more complicated example.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin. I added a more complicated example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I see the problem. When you have an Add in the numerator and the denominator `expand` distributes a "negative" power into the denominator:

```
In [45]: expr = (a*x + b*x)*(1/x)*(1/(c + d))

In [46]: expr
Out[46]: 
a⋅x + b⋅x
─────────
x⋅(c + d)

In [47]: expand(expr)
Out[47]: 
   a⋅x         b⋅x   
───────── + ─────────
c⋅x + d⋅x   c⋅x + d⋅x
```

It's less obvious with the exponential function because it shows in the numerator

```
In [48]: expr.subs(x, exp(t))
Out[48]: 
⎛   t      t⎞  -t
⎝a⋅ℯ  + b⋅ℯ ⎠⋅ℯ  
─────────────────
      c + d
```

however expand still treats it as belonging to the denominator just as a power `E**(-t)` would.

```
In [51]: expand_mul(expr.subs(x, exp(t)))
Out[51]: 
       t             t   
    a⋅ℯ           b⋅ℯ    
─────────── + ───────────
   t      t      t      t
c⋅ℯ  + d⋅ℯ    c⋅ℯ  + d⋅ℯ
```

I can't think of an easier way to do it than this:

```
In [84]: factor_terms(sum(powsimp(factor_terms(cancel(a))) for a in Add.make_args(myExpr.expand())))
Out[84]: 
    -t⋅(d + e + f)       -t⋅(a + b + c)
c₁⋅ℯ               + c₂⋅ℯ              
───────────────────────────────────────
                c₁ + c₂
```

Comment: Numerator/ Denominator : It is exactly my problem. Your answer is very wonderfull. Thanks a lot.